# Prove that matrix $\mathbf{A^H A}$ is Hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, symmetric-matrices

I have a $M \times N$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$, such that $\mathbf{A^HA}$ is a Hermitian matrix and $M < N$. Is there any way by which I can prove mathematically that $\mathbf{A^H A}$ is Hermitian.

Or should $\mathbf{A}$ have some special structure which can be used to show that $\mathbf{A^H}$ is Hermitian.

The matrix in my problem is such that the correlation between the rows decreases with the separation. In other words, the correlation between the rows of the matrix will be a sinc function.  Similar property is also observed for the column matrix. In general the $\mathbf{A}$ has the following form,

$$\mathbf{A}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & e^{j\pi \theta_1} & e^{j \pi 2\theta_1} & \dots & e^{j \pi N \theta_1} \\
     1       & e^{j\pi \theta_2} & e^{j \pi 2\theta_2} & \dots & e^{j \pi N \theta_2} \\
     1       & e^{j\pi \theta_3} & e^{j \pi 2\theta_3} & \dots & e^{j \pi N \theta_3} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: $A^HA$ is always Hermitian.

Answer (score 3):

Using $(UV)^H=V^HU^H$, $(A^HA)^H=A^H(A^H)^H=A^HA$.